# CDF of the sum of n independent random variables

Tags: probability

What is the cdf of $Z=X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_n$ where $X_i$ has general cdf $G_i$? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is a cdf? $\hspace{0cm}$

Comment: @TaraB, mostly likely the [cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the cumulative distribution function. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: It's the integral of the pdf of the sum ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
it's G_1*...*G_n where * is the convolution.
```

Ok what I said was wrong sorry. I thought because you can commute integral and convolution it led to that but I went to fast. Actually, for n=2 it's
$$ G_1 * g_2 $$ 
where g_2 is the distribution of X_2. 
That you can prove by integrating the convolution g_1*g_2 (which is itself an integral) and commute the integrals.
So for any n it's
$$ G_1*g_2*...*g_n $$

Comment: Are you sure that the convolution of the **CDFs** gives the CDF of the sum? Would you be willing to provide a proof? Not a link to a web site or a reference to a book where you claim the proof can be found, but the actual proof itself?

Comment: I was thinking you could use convolutions if dealing with pdfs-I didn't think that worked with cdf's as well?

Answer (score 0):

Computer either the moment generating function or the probability generating function and hope you can recognize the result. Even if you can't you can use these two calculate the moments which is often enough.